# ps aux auto close app

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jake

I'm trying to setup a task to kill certain server processes when the server gets into a weird state such as when it fails to boot one process, but another process gets keeps running and so not everything boots up. This is mainly a task for development so you can do `jake killall` to kill all processes associated with this project.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the `pid` after doing: `ps aux | grep [p]rocess\ name | {HOW DO I GET THE PID NOW?}` and then after getting the ID how do I pass that to `kill -9 {PID HERE}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PID is the second column, so you can do

```
ps aux | grep [p]rocess\ name | awk '{print $2}'
```

All together,

```
my_pid=$(ps aux | grep [p]rocess\ name | awk '{print $2}')
kill -9 $my_pid
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also you `killall <program>` or `pkill <program>` or `pgrep <program>`

Comment: I tried this, but there are a lot of processes with the same program (node). AFAIK, I'd need the process name, not program name.